# Solution project failed to load

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

I have database project which work until we migrated visual studio from VS2015 to VS2017. Now one project failing to load and I can't understand why?
Everything was installed what need to work with reports. Different report project works perfectly.

AS you can see the last project in solution was not loaded
[image]

Then I try reload it I am getting 
C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx.rptproj : error  : There is an error in XML document (2, 2).

Project xml looks like
[image]

Looking for solution or hint how I could load the project?
ps. on diferent machine with VS2017 project work and both have the same version from source control

Comment: It should say whats wrong in the output window, if not, try to reload the project (and then it should be there).

Comment: I understand that you want to keep your content private, but if the error is actually in the name itself, then it might be hard to recieve a proper answer to.

Comment: The tools version is different in 17 from 15.  Build a new empty Project in VS 17 and then manually edit project file so versions match a new project in VS17.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found solution :
First created empty report project and changed in the line

```
<Project xmlns:xsi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

To

```
<Project xmlns:xsi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="15.0">
```

Then clicked reload solution and it workded.

Thank you for help solve problem especially jdweng for given idea

Comment: Correct I did not even have to make a blank project. I just added the additional information to that Project Tag and re-added my reports and data sources.

Comment: Thanks! I also had to re-add all my project files!

Answer (score 6):

Open the source folder and delete the `.rptproj.user` file.  Then, reload the project in VS.

Comment: This should be your first option, then go for the one below, since that can cause headache for other people with older versions of the SSRS toolings.